# Changing the text in a textbox when selecting a row in the table

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable

I'm making a program where the text in a textbox or a label will change when I select a row in a table. Like for example, I have three rows with 1, 2 and 3 as the data respectively. When I click the second row, the textbox should output 2 as the text. If I click the third row, it should output 3.

What event should I use without clicking a button?

Comment: You might want to take the [tour] and revisit [ask]. Your question is rather broad as we would need to write all code for you. You get better answers if you show us where you started with and then elaborate a bit on where you are stuck. That makes the posts useful for you and future visitors.

Comment: @rene No i mean what event should I use to do that?

Comment: Do you have problems with [Listening for events](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#modelchange) or with [editors and renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)

Comment: @rene No, but I don't know what event should I use. There is no action or item listener in a JTable. I don't what to use to make the textbox's text automatically change when I select a row from a table.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `ListSelectionListener` for events triggered when an item was selected in the list:

```
list.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        // called when list selection changed
    }
});
```

Detailed instructions and methods for `ListSelectionEvent` are available [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html).

Comment: I'll try this one. Thanks